# Doors and mounts

Tags: nethack

I just started a Knight and mounted my Horse upon reaching level 2. I noticed you cannot kick doors while mounted. What's the best way to go about traversing doors while mounted?

Comment: It should be pointed out, that if you have ways of opening doors non-destructively (i.e. the door is unlocked or you have a means of unlocking it), you should prefer those regardless of whether you have a mount or not, since kicking doors in wakes monsters (including sleeping nymphs, which can be quite annoying) and angers shopkeepers if the door belonged to them.

Comment: @sepp2k: Understood. I've kicked down a door that was only stuck (not locked) and faced the wrath of a shopkeeper many times. I really can't make any progress in this game. The whole "everything is based on luck" thing is pretty irritating because you can't do anything about it.

Comment: @Itake: But you can do something about it: don't kick in doors that are not locked. If a shop door is locked there will be an engraving saying "Closed for inventory" in front of it, so you can tell when a locked door belongs to a shop. So if you only kick in doors which are locked and do not have a closed-for-inventory-sign, you'll be safe from angry shopkeepers.

Comment: @sepp2k: That part of my comment wasn't regarding doors. It was regarding the nature of the game. But thanks for the info, I had no idea shopkeeper doors had signs/engravings on them.

Comment: @Itake: Still, there are very few "bad luck" things that you can't protect yourself against or can't recover from. Of course a game where you find a wand of wishing on level 1 will be easier than one where a polymorph trap on level 8 (or bones file on level 4) created an arch lich, but [Marvin](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Marvin)'s ascension rate of over 80% goes to show that an (extraordinarily) skilled player can still win the vast majority of games no matter what the RNG throws at you.

Comment: @sepp2k: You mean an **enlightened** player can win the vast majority of games. If NetHack were skill-based it'd be winnable 100% of the time. There's a pretty big difference between skill and knowledge. Not many games rely heavily on both (e.g. Quake, Counter-Strike, StarCraft).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best scenario is to get an unlocking item. Which is either a *credit card*, a *lockpick*, or best of all a *skeleton key*. You can apply these items while still mounted in order to open the door efficiently. And, as an added benefit, keep the door in operation should you need it for anything else. A *wand of opening* or the spell of *knock* will also have the same effect, but the tools are free to use.

Failing that, if you have a *wand of striking* or the spell of *force bolt*, you can always break down doors with the ray and maintain your mounted position. Be prepared for any consequences like shattering items or hitting creatures that are behind the door, though.

If you lack these kinds of items, you'll need to either find another way into the room (perhaps a *wand of digging*, if you want to just make your own shortcut), or you'll have to hop off and give the door a swift kick yourself before mounting again.

Comment: I figured (and feared) that I would have to dismount to open the door normally. Thank you.

Comment: @I: it's often a good idea to delay riding the horse anyway, since it won't gain HP and levels as quickly while you're riding (it won't attack monsters on its own while you're mounted), and jousting early is a bad idea as your lance is likely to break if you use it for jousting before you've increased your luck.

Comment: @Wooble: Thanks for the tips. I didn't think about that at all.